# Ошибка передачи типа конструктора объекту в main C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, конструктор, константа, строковый-литерал

```
#include<cstring>
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Printed_edition
{
protected:
    static int N;
    char name[25];
    int page;
    char type[25];
    int i;
    Printed_edition *temp;
public:
    Printed_edition(void)
    {
        N++;
        cout << "Counstructor without parameters!base!" << endl;
        page = 0;
        temp = this;
    }
    Printed_edition(char Name[], char Type[], int Value)
    {
        SetName(Name);
        SetType(Type);
        page = Value;
    }
    virtual ~Printed_edition(void)
    {
        cout << "Destructor" << endl;
    }
    virtual void show()
    {
        N = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            cout << temp->GetName() << endl;
        }
    }
    void SetName(char Value[])
    {
            strcpy_s(name, Value);
    }
    void SetType(char Value[])
    {
            strcpy_s(type, Value);
    }
    void SetPage(int Value)
    {
        page = Value;
    }
    char *GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    char *GetType()
    {
        return type;
    }
    int GetPage()
    {
        return page;
    }
};

class magazine : virtual public Printed_edition
{
    magazine()
    {
        cout << "Counstructo without parameters" << endl;
        page = 0;
    }
    magazine(char Name[], char Type[], int Page)
    {
        strcpy_s(name,Name);
        strcpy_s(type, Type);
        page = Page;
    }
     magazine(const magazine &a)
    {
        cout << "Copying Constuctor" << endl;
        name = new char[strlen(a.name) + 1];
        strcpy_s(name, a.name);
        type = new char[strlen(a.type) + 1];
        strcpy_s(type, a.type);
        page = a.page;
    }
    virtual ~magazine()
    {
        cout << "Destructor" << endl;
    }

};
class book : virtual public Printed_edition
{
private:
    char genre[25];
public:
    book()
    {
        cout << "Constructor without parameters" << endl;
        page = 0;
    }
    book(char Name[], char Type[], int Page, char Genre[])
    {
        strcpy_s(name, Name);
        strcpy_s(type, Type);
        page = Page;
        strcpy_s(genre, Genre);
    }
    book(const book &a)
    {
        cout << "Copying Constructor" << endl;
        name = new char[strlen(a.name) + 1];
        strcpy_s(name, a.name);
        page = a.page;
        type = new char[strlen(a.type) + 1];
        strcpy_s(type, a.type);
        genre = new char[strlen(a.genre) + 1];
        strcpy_s(genre, a.genre);
    }
    ~book()
    {
        cout << "Destructor" << endl;
    }
    void show()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            cout << temp->GetName() << endl;
        }
    }
    void SetGenre(char GENRE[])
    {
            strcpy_s(genre, GENRE);
    }
    char *GetGenre()
    {
        return genre;
    }
};

class learning_book : virtual public Printed_edition, book
{
private:
    char lessontype[25];
public:
    learning_book()
    {
        cout << "Constructor wp" << endl;
        page = 0;
    }
    learning_book(char Name[], char Type[], int Page, char Lessontype[])
    {
        cout << "Constructor with parameters" << endl;
        strcpy_s(name, Name);
        strcpy_s(type, Type);
        page = Page;
        SetLesson(Lessontype);
    }
    learning_book(const learning_book &a)
    {
        cout << "Copying Constructor" << endl;
        name = new char[strlen(a.name) + 1];
        strcpy_s(name, a.name);
        page = a.page;
        type = new char[strlen(a.type) + 1];
        strcpy_s(type, a.type);
        lessontype = new char[strlen(a.lessontype) + 1];
        strcpy_s(lessontype, a.lessontype);
    }
    ~learning_book()
    {
        cout << "Destructor" << endl;

    }
    /*void show()
    {
        if (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            cout << temp->GetName() << endl;
        }
    }*/
    void SetLesson(char LT[])
    {
            strcpy_s(lessontype, LT);
    }
    char GetLessonType()
    {
        return lessontype[25];
    }
};


int main()
{
    // N = 0;
    magazine b1("Tall", "magazine", 12);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: А выделить минимальный самодостаточный компилируемый пример - не судьба? :) И вообще - после того, как вы объявляете `char name[25];`, а потом присваиваете `name = new char[strlen(a.name) + 1];` - что тут говорить о передаче чего-то там куда-то там... Кстати, указанной вами ошибки я у себя в VC++ 2017 не увидел...

Comment: Также не могу иницилизировать счетчик N .

Comment: Ну наверное здесь нужен весь код чтобы все смогли разобраться

Comment: Где ваш вопрос-то?

Comment: http://i.im-h.ru/i689810b9swvm

Comment: http://i.im-h.ru/i689813bm1r86

Comment: @Max Land Что за ошибка? Это ошибка времени компиляции или времени выполнения? Приведите соответствующее сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас конструктор с параметрами объявлен следующим образом

```
magazine(char Name[], char Type[], int Page)
{
    // ...
}
```

который вы вызываете как

```
magazine b1("Tall", "magazine", 12);
```

то есть вызываете его, передав ему в качестве аргументов строковые литералы `"Tall"` и `"magazine"`

Однако строковые литералы в C++ имеют тип константных символьных массивов.

Поэтому объявите конструктор как

```
magazine( const char Name[], const char Type[], int Page)
{
    // ...
}
```

то есть добавив квалификатор `const` для первых двух параметров.

То же самое сделайте и для конструкторов других классов, которые в качестве аргументов принимают символьные массивы и, в частности, строковые литералы.

Comment: Спасибо но теперь ошибка заключается в этом i.im-h.ru/i689813bm1r86

Comment: @Max Land Извините, но это уже другой вопрос. Закройте этот вопрос, внеся изменения в код, как я указал, и затем создайте новый вопрос относительно новых ошибок, так как в результате изменений ваш код уже меняется..